# How do I add controls other than buttons/actions to toolbars in Qt, such as text boxes and combo boxes?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, qt4, qtoolbar

From the screenshot featured on this page http://www.kde.gr.jp/~ichi/qt/designer-manual-3.html it seems like this functionality was available in Qt3. Was it removed in Qt4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can do so from within Designer. You can add other widgets programmatically using [QToolBar::addWidget()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtoolbar.html#addWidget).